# Is the 51% attack the only technical reason no country will ever adopt Bitcoin as a state currency?

Tags: attack, cryptocurrency

Is the 51% attack the only technical reason no country will adopt Bitcoin as a state currency?

Let's suppose a country with a GDP size less than 300 Billion USD adopt the Bitcoin as an official currency. It will be very easy to crush or take control of state currency if a country like the US or China invests to run 51% of the mining pool.

Comment: Well, having to wait 30min+ for a transaction to be valid also isn't a nice feature...

Comment: @SEJPM another valid reason!

Comment: Bitcoin is not regulatable. Users are anonymous, and cross-border, laundry is trivially easy and difficult to trace, and value is highly unstable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about economic implications and/or policy around Bitcoin, not the underlying crypto.

Comment: the 51% is universal with blockchain.  it might we worth riding this one out